# VBS - how to run two browser one is full screen and another is minimised?

Tags: shell, google-chrome, vbscript, windows-8.1

I have a kiosk where i need to run Chrome.exe as --kiosk and another Chrome.exe minimised. Using regedit run method VBS is executed.

Problem is on reboot it is messed up always the minimised chrome.exe does not start as minimised, always its shows on top of --kiosk mode.

How can i be 100% sure then when VBS is executed one chrome is running minimised and another is --kiosk mode?

```
Dim url
Dim shell

-- Part 1 - "has to run as --kiosk, always on screen never ever exit from the display screen"
url = "www.stackoverflow.com"
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", url, "", "", 1

-- Part 2 - "has to run as minimised when PC starts and VBS is executed, it should never ever pretend to show on screen."
url = "www.icanhazip.com"
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", url, "", "", 1
```

This script is not working for me, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Shell.Application`, use the `Run` method of `WScript.Shell`. Here I assume that chrome.exe is either on the path or in the current working directory:

```
Option Explicit

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Call .Run("chrome.exe www.icanhazip.com", 6, false)
  Call .Run("chrome.exe --kiosk www.stackoverflow.com", 1, false)
End With
```

The second parameter is the window style.

[Documentation Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: Did you tested it yet?